# Is the boundary of a connected set connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

SOLVED - check out the comments or directly this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170337/connectedness-of-the-boundary/170355#170355).

I was wondering if the boundary of an unbounded component $C$ of the complement of a bounded connected open set $U$ must be connected (in $\mathbb R^n, n\geq 2$).

As the complement of $C$ (i.e., the sum of $U$ and the bounded components of its complement) is connected, the answer is positive if the following claim is true:

> A connected open set $A$ in $\mathbb R^n$ $(n\geq 1)$ has disconnected complement if and only if it has disconnected boundary.

There is a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227734/18493), but one crucial step seems false (see below). I'm looking for a correct proof (or a counterexample, but I hope it is true).

---

I had two doubts about the proof mentioned - one of them is the above probably false step and the other is already solved:

- Why can we join $x$ and $y$ through the complement of $A$? We would need something like connectedness of interior of this complement, wouldn't we? UPDATE: YES, see below.
- Why this homotopy cannot exist? UPDATE2: solved, see below.

**Update:** The statement about joining $x$ and $y$ seems false: even if $A$ and its complement are connected and the boundary is connected with $x,y \in \partial A \cap \partial\mathrm{int} (\mathbb R^n \setminus A)$, it is not true, that we can join $x,y$ by a curve in $X\setminus A$. It is enough to consider a [Warsaw sinusoid](http://dyinglovegrape.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/counter-examples-the-topologists-sine-curve/) in the plane with closed balls attached to its different path-components, and take $x$ and $y$ at the boundaries of these balls.

Note that we can improve this example so that any point in the boundary of $A$ is in the boundary of interior of its complement - so the assumption about regular openness of $A$ proposed in the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170337/18493) doesn't help.

**Update2:** 
The argument for non-existence of the homotopy trivialising the loop can be derived from the tricky function proposed by Dejan Govc in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170355/18493) to the original question (in the part entitled "Added"). The loop composed with this function is a nontrivial loop in $S^1$, so the original loop also is nontrivial, a contradiction.

Comment: I've finally rewritten my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170337/connectedness-of-the-boundary/170355#170355), sorry for taking so long. If there's any point that needs clarifying, comments are more than welcome. By the way, you are right - it is not necessarily possible to connect $x$ and $y$ through the complement. My answer circumvents this by only avoiding one of the sets in the separation of the boundary.