# Where is the "thread" of a river?

Tags: geometry, cartography

Lawyers speak of the "thread" of a river.  When the boundary between two counties or states is a river, it is usually the "thread" of the river, a path running along the center of the river.  (In England, I suspect this has applied primarily to boundaries between counties.)  If a line is drawn from a point on one bank to a corresponding point on the opposite bank, one can take the midpoint to be a point on the "thread", but **which point on the opposite bank is the corresponding point when the river meanders erratically,** as they all do (but some more than others)**?**  I am inclined to doubt that lawyers have clearly answered this, and to **suspect that some substantial components of any reasonable answer can be contributed only by mathematicians.**

Exceptions include:

- The northern boundary of Kentucky.  The whole of the Ohio River is in Kentucky; the states north of it, Ohio, Indiana, and Illinois, begin at the north bank.  I think this goes back to an act of Parliament after the Seven Years' War in 1763, declaring the Ohio to be the southern boundary of Canada, which became an English colony at that time.  (This is alluded to in the language about a "fit instrument" in the Declaration of Independence.)
- The boundary between Delaware and New Jersey, which puts the Delaware River entirely in Delaware, so that New Jersey begins at the west bank.
- The boundary between Vermont and New Hampshire (surely the most colorful story of weird politics in the history of the U.S.A., if not of the Universe).  The Connecticut River is in New Hampshire; Vermont begins at the west bank.  On July 20, 1764, King George III decreed this after a scandalously ex-parte hearing, with the later result that the half of the Constitution of Vermont before its amendment-in-its-entirety in 1793 was a list of grievances against the government of New York, and the further later result that in a lawsuit that lasted from 1915 through 1933, a federal court ended up upholding the King's decision.

But dozens of boundaries between states in the U.S.A. follow the "thread" of a river, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Maybe it is the locus of midpoints of normals drawn from one bank?

Comment: @AvZ : Which one?  Perhaps one could say the left bank or the right bank.  But which?

Comment: I'm not precisely sure about how to formalize this, or whether it yields a curve, but maybe something like imagining both banks puff out (i.e. draw circles of the same radius about each point on the banks, take their union) at some rate and then, wherever the two banks "first meet" is the thread.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, That's the problem, you will get different locus from each bank... Average them maybe?

Comment: How about we choose the thread to be the set of points which have the same minimum distance from both banks.

In formal terms, let $Y$ be the set of points on one bank, and $Z$ be the set of points on the other bank. $x$ is now one with the thread if and only if $$\min\limits_{y\in Y}d(x,y)=\min\limits_{z\in Z}d(x,z)$$

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: Yup that's pretty much the gist of the answer I just wrote up with some conditions needed for nice properties.

Comment: @AvZ : It's not clear how to average them.  If you have two points, you can find their average.  But which two points?  Which point on one curve corresponds to which on the other?

Comment: The [medial axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) of the region enclosed by the banks might be a reasonable definition. (This seems to be what @Meelo is getting at.)

Comment: @user86418: But using the medial axis would mean that you lose information about which bank the closest points are from, which also means you get funny isolated points in all the small cavities of the banks, which is surely not reasonable for a boundary. Also, the definition I gave is part of the medial axis that excludes those irrelevant points.

Comment: @user21820 : Your comment definitely calls for an example.

Comment: Say we have banks in 2d, both being halfplanes with parallel boundaries except one has a tiny triangle cut out of it. Then a part of one of the angle bisectors of the triangle will be on the medial axis simply because those points are equidistant to multiple points on that bank, but what you want is to be equidistant to **both** banks, hence my definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Notation

Let $d(x,y)$ be the distance between $x$ and $y$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $d(x,S) = \inf_{y \in S} d(x,y)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $d(S,T) = \inf_{(x,y) \in S \times T} d(x,y)$ for any $S,T \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.

### A possible definition of a river's thread

Take any non-empty closed disjoint sets $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^3$ [corresponding to the two banks].

Let $T = \{ x : d(x,A) = d(x,B) \}$ for any $r \in [0,1]$.

Then $T$ can be considered the middle boundary between $A$ and $B$.

### Properties of this thread

**Regions**

Let $A' = \{ x : d(x,A) < d(x,B) \}$.

Let $B' = \{ x : d(x,B) < d(x,A) \}$.

Then $A',B'$ are clearly open since $d$ is continuous and hence $T$ is closed.

**Closest-Point**

For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$:

$d(x,A) = d(x,y)$ for some $y \in A$ because:

Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ such that $d(x,y_n) \to d(x,A)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Then $(y_n)$ is bounded and has some cluster point $y$ [by Bolzano-Weierstrass].

Thus $y \in A$ [because $A$ is closed].

[This means that there is a point in $A$ closest to $x$. Similarly for $B$.]

**Disjoint-Separation**

$T,A',B'$ are clearly disjoint.

$A \subseteq A'$ because:

For any $x \in A$:

If $d(x,B) = 0$:

Let $y \in B$ such that $d(x,y) = d(x,B)$ [by Closest-Point].

Then $x = y \in B$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $d(x,B) > 0 = d(x,A)$ and hence $x \in A'$.

Similarly $B \subseteq B'$ and hence $T$ is disjoint from both $A$ and $B$.

**No-holes**

For any topological sphere $C \subseteq A'$ having no point of $B$ in its interior:

Let $D$ be the topological ball corresponding to $C$.

For any $x \in D$:

Let $y \in B$ such that $d(x,y) = d(x,B)$ [by Closest-Point].

Let $L$ be the line segment from $x$ to $y$.

Let $z = L \cap C$ [which exists because $B$ is outside $C$].

Then $d(x,A) \le d(x,z) + d(z,A) < d(x,z) + d(z,B) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y) = d(x,y)$

$= d(x,B)$.

Therefore $D \subseteq A'$.

**Connected-Separation**

If $A$ is connected, then $A'$ is path-connected because:

For any $x \in A'$:

Let $y \in A$ such that $d(x,y) = d(x,A)$ [by Closest-Point].

Let $L$ be the line segment from $x$ to $y$.

If $z \in B'$ for some $z \in L$:

$d(x,B) \le d(x,z) \le d(x,y) = d(x,A)$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $L \subseteq A'$.

Thus $L \cup A$ is connected.

Therefore $A'$ is connected and hence path-connected because $A'$ is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Therefore if $A,B$ are both connected, then $A',B'$ will be both path-connected [and the whole space $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be divided into exactly two 'pieces' separated by $T$]. I believe but cannot prove that $T$ will in this case be connected. It is not necessarily path-connected; $T$ can be the Koch snowflake if $A,B$ are the inside and outside of it, in which case no two points in $T$ are path-connected.

### Comments

$x \mapsto \dfrac{d(x,A)}{d(x,A)+d(x,B)}$ is a continuous function that is $0$ on exactly $A$ and $1$ on exactly $B$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ on exactly $T$. See [Urysohn function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma) for a generalization.

If either $A$ or $B$ is bounded, then $d(A,B) > 0$. Otherwise it is possible that $d(A,B) = 0$ despite $A,B$ being closed and disjoint. But this has nothing to do with the river thread so it belongs in this section.

Whether this definition is 'used' in real life I do not not know.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/170337/21820 seems to be exactly what I hypothesized and an answer purports to prove it via rather advanced methods (I didn't check it).