# Is every boundary of a connected subset of $S^2$ whose closure does not separate $S^2$ a Jordan curve?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $C$ be a nonempty connected subset of $S^2$ and $\partial C$ be the boundary of $C$.

> If $\bar C$ (closure) does not separate $S^2$, is $\partial C\cong S^1$?

This seems very true, but I think proof won't be easy. Is this statement true? How do I prove this?

Comment: This is false, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170337/connectedness-of-the-boundary/170355#170355) for an example. Also, consider a single point.

Comment: @DejanGovc Thank you. However, say it is infinite, then what additional condition would it be to make this statement holds?

Comment: in those cases also you might find some counter example, like if youy consider a line joining north and south poles, or if you consider $S^2$\ {a point} and alll...so I dont think it is an interesting problem but ofcourse you can try to make it interesting  by adding some strong conditions like $C^c$ is simple connected and has non-empty interior...