# Boundary of bounded connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, whose complement is also connected, is connected

Tags: general-topology

So I know that there are other threads available on this topic, but there seems to be proofs that miss some details and I was wondering if someone could extrapolate or give a more detailed proof. Namely, if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$  is a bounded connected open subset and $U^c$ is connected then $\partial A$ is connected as well.

Comment: Consider an open annulus, which is a counterexample to the claim in the title...

Comment: Then it's complement isn't connected which contradicts our hypothesis. So that example doesn't work.

Comment: Are you familiar with Poincare/Alexander duality?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with Poincare/ Alexander duality. How does this fit into establishing the result above? I don't quite see it.

Comment: @enigma, it is a counterexample to the claim made in your **title** (as I wrote). It is a really bad idea to pick a title which claims something different than the actual question and which, to boot, is false!

Comment: Sorry Mariano. I'll make the title more specific

Comment: @Enigma: have you seen my [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/170355/19588) using the fundamental group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument using homology. Suppose that $K=\partial U$ is not connected. Then there exists a pair of disjoint open subsets $A, B\subset R^n$ each of which has nonempty intersection with $K$. Without loss of generality we may assume that each component of $A$ and of $B$ has nonempty intersection with $K$ (otherwise we discard these components). It follows therefore that the open sets $X=A\cup U\cup B, Y= A\cup B\cup U^c$ are both connected (since $U, U^c$ are connected and each component of $A, B$ has nonempty intersection with both $U$ and $U^c$). We have an open cover of $R^n$ by $X, Y$. Furthermore, $Z=X\cap Y= A\cup B$ is not connected. Now, apply Mayer-Vietoris sequence (integer coefficients) for the reduced homology for the open cover $\{X, Y\}$ of $R^n$. We obtain:
$$
0=H_1(R^n)\to \tilde{H}_0(Z)\to\tilde{H}_0(X)\oplus \tilde{H}_0(Y)= 0
$$ 
Hence, $\tilde{H}_0(Z)=0$, which contradicts the fact that $Z$ is not path connected. qed