# Reference request: connectedness of the boundary of a set and that of its complement

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, connectedness

It is said here (:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227734 ) that  a connected open set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has disconnected complement if and only if it has disconnected boundary. Where can I find a readable proof of this and related topics? Thanks for your reply.